# Find a specific value of a string between two chars/strings without knowing its value

Tags: javascript, regex

String example: `"{something}"` or `"{word: something}"`

What I need to do is get 'something', so the text between two specific parts of the string, in these case `{`-`}` and `{word:`-`}` (The 'something' part can change in every string, I never know what it is).

I tried using string.find() or regex but I didn't come up with a conclusion. What's the quickest and best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a *capture group* inside a regex.

```js
> const match = /\{([^}]+)\}/.exec('{foo}')
> match[1]
'foo'
```

The stuff in the parens, `([^}]+)`, matches any character but `}`, repeated at least once. The parens make it be captured; the first captured group is indexed as `match[1]`.